# AngularJS service not returning promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I'm trying to load some data from my database using AngularJS. 
I have a service that should get the data and a controller that uses it.

See my code below:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .factory('panelService', ['$http', function ($http) {

        return {
            async: function () {
                return $http.get('/test');  // this returns promise
            }
        };

    }]);


angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('panelCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

        var promise = panelService.async()
        promise.then(
            function(payload){
                $scope.user = payload.data;
            }
        )

}]);
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. No data is loaded and I don't see any JSON object arriving at the browser. However, if I replace `panelService.async()` with `$http.get('/test')` in my controller it works fine. So my guess is that my service has an error or it is not properly called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The soulution is to inject the service into the controller like this:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('panelCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'panelService', function ($scope, $http, panelService) {

        var promise = panelService.async()
        promise.then(
            function(payload){
                $scope.user = payload.data;
            }
        )

}]);
```

Answer (score 4):

In order for you to understand the problem and how to fix it by yourself the next time, lets go through the steps you need to do when something isn't working as expected in angularjs.

First thing, check the console. you should be getting an error something like:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'async' of undefined ...`

Which should get you thinking why the parent object of `async` is undefined, and a quick viewing of your code would reveal that you forgot to inject the `panelService` in your controller.